# FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile); crashes on API 18

Tags: java, android, vcf-vcard

I have the following code:

```
File vcfFile = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "generated.vcf");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
...
```

It works fine on newer APIs, but on API 18 it crashes.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /generated.vcf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

I think this is the reason, but I can't find a work-around. It is the main feature of the app, so removing it isn't really an option for me.

Comment: Can you post the permissions part of your manifest?

Comment: @Ascorbin There are no permissions there, the App doesnt need any at least on newer APIs. What permissions would I have to implement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to write to `getExternalFilesDir()` on Android 4.3 and older. Only on Android 4.4+ can you skip it for that location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the permission to write to the external Storage. With the new API's you need to both declare the permission in the `manifest` and also ask for the permission during runtime.

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

You can check this link for further details:https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html